# MultiIndexing two dictionaries as pandas DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have two dictionaries of dictionaries as such:

```
d_old = {person1: {a1:aaa, b1:bbb, c1:ccc...}, person2:{...}, ...}  
d_new = {person1: {a1:AAA, b1:BBB, c1:CCC...}, person2:{...}, ...}
```

I'd like to align these next to each other in pandas DataFrame, using a hierarchial MultiIndexing to create something like this:

```
                 d_old  d_new  
person1    a1    aaa    AAA  
           b1    bbb    BBB  
           c1    ccc    CCC  
person2    a1    ...
```

I'm new to pandas, and while I could get multi-indexing working for a single dictionary, I'm at loss with trying to align these two. How to do that?

...also, I can't get formatting of the above table right, feel free to edit this question into more readable form if you know how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) with [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html)ed `DataFrames`:

```
d_old = {'person1': {'a1':'aaa', 'b1':'bbb', 'c1':'ccc'},
         'person2':{'a1':'cc', 'b1':'dd', 'c1':'ee'},}
d_new = {'person1': {'a1':'AAA', 'b1':'BBB', 'c1':'CCC'}, 
         'person2':{'a1':'AAA', 'b1':'BBB', 'c1':'CCC'}} 

df1 = pd.DataFrame(d_old)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(d_new)
print(df1)
print(df2)

print (pd.concat([df1.unstack(), df2.unstack()], keys=['df_old','df_new'], axis=1))
           df_old df_new
person1 a1    aaa    AAA
        b1    bbb    BBB
        c1    ccc    CCC
person2 a1     cc    AAA
        b1     dd    BBB
        c1     ee    CCC
```